# Django - annotation produces duplicate joins

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

The following annotation produces duplicates

```
.annotate(
        **{
            f"{key}_bundle_id": F('item__child_link__parent_item__bundle__id'),
            f"{key}_bundle_name": F('item__child_link__parent_item__bundle__name')
        }
    )
```

Both of these annotations join across a many to many table to get the id and name of the joined table. I would expect this to produce a join, and select both the id and name from the join.

Instead it duplicates the join and selects the id from 1 set and the name from the other. Is there a solution to work around this or do annotations always produce their own joins?

Here's the sql it generates:

```
SELECT T8.id as x_axis_bundle_id, T12.name as x_axis_bundle_name
....
INNER JOIN "item" ON ("gmdts"."item_id" = "item"."id")
INNER JOIN "link" ON ("item"."id" = "link"."child_id")
INNER JOIN "item" T8 ON ("link"."parent_id" = T8."id")
INNER JOIN "bundle" T9 ON (T8."id" = T9."item_id")
INNER JOIN "link" T10 ON ("item"."id" = T10."child_id")
INNER JOIN "item" T11 ON (T10."parent_id" = T11."id")
INNER JOIN "bundle" T12 ON (T11."id" = T12."item_id")
```

Comment: What if you work with `.values(**{...})`?

Comment: I find it quite strange that this happens. Are there filters in (the rest) of your queryset, since using `.filter(..)` multiple times will indeed make the same JOIN multiple times.

Comment: I need to alias the columns to include the {key} value. It could be the filters yeah, is it possible to force it to only look at the join once? It's causing some significant performance hits.

Comment: With the multiple joins it takes 11 minutes to run a query, without the duplicate join it takes 3 seconds.